# Free, scriptable, partition manager for Windows

Tags: partitioning, script, efi, windows-pe

Are there any free scriptable partition managers for windows that can create an EFI partition? (Identifier 0xEF)

**EDIT:** It needs to run on Windows XP (BartPE)

**EDIT 2:** So it seems Intel has a 32-bit utility available for download called diskpart.efi. Does anyone know how to run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297800

Comment: The diskpart version included with Windows XP (BartPE) doesn't seem to support the needed commands. Can a working version be obtained from somewhere?

Comment: http://lordoftheping.blogspot.com/2007/04/bartpe-diskpart-nightmare.html. Also, it may only work when running from a cd or dvd

Comment: That link looks great. I'll accept this as the answer, even though I haven't tried it myself. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

get Intel's **[Diskpart EFI GPT Disk Partitioning Tool](http://www.intel.com/technology/efi/diskutil_overview.htm)**

[Tutorial](http://www.techfuels.com/windows-xp/21728-how-use-diskpart-efi-utility-create-guid-partition-table-partition.html)

Comment: That download looks promising. Has a 32-bit binary that might work. Now I just have to figure out how to run it. The diskpart.efi binary doesn't seem to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for both free AND scriptable, you wanna use the DiskPart tool, in the MS WAIK toolkit.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753